# How do I prompt for input using PHP-CLI and have the input available as a variable?

Tags: php, datetime, input, command-line-interface

I am looking to make a small PHP-CLI tool that will tell me if a date that I input, is a weekend day.  I currently have the following script, which achieves some of this goal:

```
<?php
function isWeekend($date) {
return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
var_dump(isWeekend('2014-10-29')); 
?>
```

It currently works well (outputs true or false), but I must update the source each time I want to test a date.  It would be easier if I could prompt for date (user input), and then use that input to calculate the date, preferably without using HTML elements, as I am currently running the script via the CLI.

Has anyone else managed to achieve what I was looking to do? I don't need validation, as its a tool that only I will use, and I will be sure to use the correct date structure each time I use it.

Comment: Why do you need to update the source code each time? That function looks reusable to me.

Comment: You've posted your question asking the wrong thing.  Your question is "How do I prompt for input using PHP-CLI and have the input available as a variable?"

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Found it difficult to figure out what to ask, but your suggestion is perfect. Appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
<?php
fwrite(STDOUT, "Enter the date\n");
$date = fgets(STDIN);      
$isWeekend = (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
fwrite(STDOUT, "Response: $isWeekend");  
exit(0); 
?>
```

This is what i am getting:

```
C:\xampp\php>php test.php
Enter the date
2014-11-30
Response: 1
C:\xampp\php>php test.php
Enter the date
2014-12-01
Response:
C:\xampp\php>
```

Comment: This looks nice and simple, which is definitely what I am looking for. However, I do not appear to get any input other than the date I enter.

Just to confirm, the date format is:  YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: When using the code you provided, and the correct date format, the only response I get in the CLI is:   Response:

No other output is provided.

Comment: I add to the answer what i'm getting.

Comment: Thanks so much!  It appears that the console font I have hid the "1" which was echoed.  I added a line break to the fwrite statement, and now the response appears on its own line.

Comment: You can try this too (like Andrew suggest):

`<?php    
$isWeekend = (date('N', strtotime($argv[1])) >= 6);
fwrite(STDOUT, "Response: $isWeekend");  
exit(0); 
?>`

And run with:

C:\xampp\php>php test.php 2014-11-30

Answer (score 3):

when run from the command propmpt

```
php scriptname.php 2014-10-29 secondarg
```

the user input will be contained in

```
$argv[1]

$argv[2] //secondarg etc
```

of course,

```
strtotime($argv[1]);
```

will return false on failure

Comment: `register_argc_argv` is by default `Off`, so I would recommend using `$_SERVER['argv']`.